# How to merge label columns into a single tag based on column names?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm working with a dataset that has a text comment and individual columns for each label that the comment could be categorized under. Each comment can have multiple labels assigned. From these label columns, I'd like to create a single column summarizing all applicable labels.

For example, using movie genres:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie Title':['Movie 1', 'Movie 2', 'Movie 3', 'action': [0, 1, 0], 'comedy': [1, 1, 0], 'drama': [0, 1, 1]})

print(sample_df)
Movie Title     action  comedy  drama
Movie 1         1       1       1
Movie 2         1       0       1
Movie 3         0       0       1
```

After adding the label summary column, the dataset should look like this:

```
Movie Title     action  comedy  drama  genres
Movie 1         1       1       1      [action, comedy, drama] 
Movie 2         1       0       1      [action, drama]
Movie 3         0       0       1      [drama]
```

This is exactly what the *inverse_transform* function of `sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer` does, but I'm starting off with multiple binary labels (e.g. already binarized) so unfortunately that's not an option.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this using `dot` from @WenYoBen's playbook.

```
sample_df['genres'] = sample_df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(sample_df.columns[1:] + ',').str[:-1].str.split(',')

sample_df
```

Output:

```
  Movie Title  action  comedy  drama                   genres
0     Movie 1       0       1      0                 [comedy]
1     Movie 2       1       1      1  [action, comedy, drama]
2     Movie 3       0       0      1                  [drama]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach with `melt` and `groupby`

```
s = sample_df.melt('Movie Title', var_name='genres')
new_df = s[s['value'].eq(1)].groupby('Movie Title').genres.apply(list)
sample_df.merge(new_df, on='Movie Title')
```

Output:

```
  Movie Title  action  comedy  drama                   genres
0     Movie 1       1       1      1  [action, comedy, drama]
1     Movie 2       1       0      1          [action, drama]
2     Movie 3       0       0      1                  [drama]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the columns with a list comprehension:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:]
df['genres'] = [s.columns[x].to_list() for x in s.astype(bool).to_numpy()]

#  Movie Title  action  comedy  drama                   genres
#0     Movie 1       0       1      0                 [comedy]
#1     Movie 2       1       1      1  [action, comedy, drama]
#2     Movie 3       0       0      1                  [drama]
```